# spyne - How to get a wrapping element surrounding a complex type

Tags: python, xml, spyne

I want to recreate the following wsdl type definition

```
<!-- Existent non spyne specification -->
<s:element name="GetVehiclesResponse">
   <s:complexType>
       <s:sequence>
         <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="s1:vehiclesResponse"/>
         <s:element ... />
    </s:sequence> 
  </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

How do i get there? Cause when inheriting from ComplexModel my result looks similar to this

```
<!-- Result from ComplexModel -->
<xs:complexType name="GetVehiclesResponse">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ... />
    ...
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Should I implement a class that is deriving from `ComplexModelBase`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two notations are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks didn't know that